# Asp.Net MVC View: Create and Relationship tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a message board in ASP.Net MVC and when the user creates a new Post they must select a category, when I create a view (Create) the field (Categories) doesnt appear?

The database has a middle table MessageToCatRel which contains a messageID and a CatId. I think this is what is confusing MVC. At the moment i am doing the following, but dont like the idea of using the Request.Form. How can I get it to post back in the Object like the other fields?

```
  public ActionResult Create(Message messageToCreate) //Post back from Message Post
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    this.LoadCategoryViewData();
                    return View();
                }

                //Now try and save this in the Database     /

/And Save
                IMessageRepository repo = new MessageRepository();
                MessageCategory curCatRel = new MessageCategory();
                curCatRel.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Categories"]);

                messageToCreate.MessageCategories.Add(curCatRel);
                messageToCreate.CreatedBy = 1; //Temp messure
                messageToCreate.PublishDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                repo.AddMessage(messageToCreate);
                repo.Save();
```

Comment: What is the signature for the Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, doesnt really do what I wanted. I'm sticking to use ViewData for a bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public ActionResult Create(Message messageToCreate)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Create(Message messageToCreate, int Categories)
```

Is that's what you are looking for?

Maybe this?

```
public ActionResult Create(Message messageToCreate, MessageCategory category)
```

and this in markup:

```
<form ..> <input type='hidden' name='MessageCtaegory.CategoryID'>1</input></form>
```